# How do I navigate to a new page from a Popup message? I'm using the Xamarin Community Toolkit Popup

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, popup, xamarin-community-toolkit

I'm trying to navigate to a new page upon a click of button inside the popup. Here is what I have:

```
     <StackLayout>
        <Label FontSize="15" Margin="20" Text="An account with this phone number doesn't exist. Do you want to create new account?" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button BackgroundColor="{StaticResource SystemGreen}" CornerRadius="20" Margin="20" Text="Enter again"/>
            <Button BackgroundColor="{StaticResource SystemGreen}" CornerRadius="20" Margin="20" Text="Yes" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

and here is my code behind:

```
            private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new RegisterNumberEntryPage());
            }
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? It won't navigate to a new page?

Comment: It's not navigating to a new page after clicking the button. Nothing happens.

Comment: generally speaking, you should return a value to the parent page and that page should perform the navigation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Jason mentionned you should return a value from your Popup to the page that opened it, and based on the return value, you handle whether or no to navigate to another page in your calling page code.

Below is a sample of a popup returning a boolean, when true pushing `RegisterNumberEntryPage` to the navigation stack.

#### MyPopup.xaml

```
<xct:Popup x:Class="AppTest.Popups.MyPopup"
           xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:xct="clr-namespace:Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views;assembly=Xamarin.CommunityToolkit"
           x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean"
           IsLightDismissEnabled="False">

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Margin="20"
               FontSize="15"
               Text="An account with this phone number doesn't exist. Do you want to create new account?"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Margin="20"
                    CornerRadius="20"
                    Text="Enter again"/>
            <Button Margin="20"
                    CornerRadius="20"
                    Text="Yes"
                    Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</xct:Popup>
```

#### MyPopup.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MyPopup
    {
        public MyPopup() => InitializeComponent();

        void Button_Clicked(object? sender, System.EventArgs e) => Dismiss(true);
    }
```

#### PopupPage.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class PopupPage : ContentPage
    {
        public PopupPage() => InitializeComponent();

        async void OpenPopup(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var result = await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ShowPopupAsync(new MyPopup());

            if (result)
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new RegisterNumberEntryPage());
        }
    }
```

**Note**:
that you can return any type, you need to specify it in `MyPopup.xaml` `x:TypeArguments` parameter, you might also want to set `IsLightDismissEnabled` according to your requirements.

#### Official Docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/popup

Comment: Thank you,  your recommendation worked like magic. @Cfun